# Can I use IMPORTRANGE twice on a google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm having trouble using IMPORTRANGE in googlesheet because I'm trying to use it with a sheet that has data that originated from IMPORTRANGE as well.

Basically, when we use IMPORTRANGE there's usually a masterfile (where we extract the data for importing) and the resultsheet (where the data from the masterfile is imported) but I'm trying to create another sheet wherein the data that would be transferred to this new sheet will be from the resultsheet and I'm using IMPORTRANGE as the formula to perform this. So far, the only thing that comes up when I type in my formula is the first row (header) of the resultsheet only.

This is the formula I'm using:

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("{Link of sheet 1}","A:D"),"Select * WHERE (Col4='Submitted')")`

Comment: Yes, you can use `IMPORTRANGE()` twice if those are two different workbook. If in same workbook but two different sheet then no need to use `IMPORTRANGE()` for result sheet.

Comment: Please share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output. Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.